# Is any supertype and also a subtype of all types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types

I am teaching a class on TypeScript fundamentals and I am trying to really understand the relationships between basic TS types. In all articles I saw, they put the any type very close to the top of the type hierarchy. Either

```
+---------+
| unknown |
+---------+
     |
     v
  +-----+
  | any |
  +-----+
     |
     v
all other types
```

Or maybe

```
+--------------+
| any, unknown |
+--------------+
     |
     v
all other types
```

But I do not see it that way. You can assign value of all other types to an `unknown` variable but you cannot assign `unknown` value to anything. That puts it on top. But with `any`, you can assign all values of all types to `any` and **also** assign an `any` value to variables of all types. So it behaves as `uknown` and `never` at the same time. From this I would argue, that `any` stands completely aside of the type hierarchy tree not fitting anywhere in it. I would say `any` sidesteps the type system completely and in essence means "turn off typechecking"

Am I wrong?

Comment: [`unknown` wasn't added to TS until v3.0](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type) - prior to that version the `any` keyword was used for both a catch-all top-type _and also_ to opt-out of type-checking - but now `any` is only used to opt-out of type-checking. I find there are vanishingly few bona-fide reasons to ever use `any` today (e.g. `catch( err )` is now implicitly `err: unknown` but previously was also ``err: any`).

Comment: Yes, `any` is both a top and bottom type in TS and is therefore unsound. It doesn’t fit into the type system properly. But it’s there nonetheless and TS has plenty of unsound relationships that violate rules of subtyping. You can easily get `X extends Y` and `Y extends Z` without `X extends Z` even without `any`. So it depends how you want to draw your graph whether or not `any` is in there at the top *and* bottom, or whether it just doesn’t fit.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any):

> The any type is a powerful way to work with existing JavaScript, allowing you to gradually opt-in and opt-out of type checking during compilation.

So i guess your understanding is correct. `any` is a way to opt out of type checking.

But it (and also, unknown) are top types as all types are assignable to them.

From [wiki definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_type#:%7E:text=The%20top%20type%20is%20sometimes,object%20of%20the%20type%20system.) of top types:

> The top type is sometimes called also universal type, or universal supertype as all other types in the type system of interest are subtypes of it, and in most cases, it contains every possible object of the type system.

It seems that all that is required from a top type is all other types to be assignable to it, which is true of both `unknown` and `any`.